# How to open a new Window after y close a first one?

Tags: java, swing, window, frame

I'm working in this program in this the user is asked, for different types of data, but each type of data depends of the previous ones. So I created three frames, in which I place the first quiz, and now what I want is to open a new window, when the user press a button (Next) which at the same time close the first one. What I've tried so far is to change a Boolean variable when the user press that button (Next), however, I don't know how to make reference to this last variable from a new class. I'm putting the trouble in context because may you can give me a better approach tho solve this.

Comment: *"So I created three frames,.."* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1):

Opening and closing windows isn't complicated and involves nothing more than creating the window instances (such as a JFrame or JDialog) and calling `setVisible(true)` or `setVisible(false)` on them.  But having said that, how many commercial applications do you use where windows are thrown willy nilly at the user? Few because it's a user interface nightmare. Instead do your user's a favor and swap views with a CardLayout, and for the instance where you occasionally need to get information modally ,use a modal dialog such as a JDialog set to modal or a JOptionPane.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by typing these lines in (Next) button's ActionListener method:

```
dispose();
NewJFrame n = NweJFrame();
n.setVisible(true);
```

The line `dispose();` will close your previous window and your another new window suppose named NewJFrame will be opened by this two line

```
NewJFrame n = NweJFrame();
n.setVisible(true);
```

But before that you must have to write the code of NewJFrame as you have written for your previous window.

Answer (score 0):

this code was only half successfull.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
if (f2 is Form2)
{
    f2.Show();
    this.Close();
}
else 
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.Show();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your answer is relevant.  Your code looks like C#, as it uses the `is` operator, has `{`s on new lines and has method names beginning with capital letters.  However, this is a Java question.